# Immediate unlock/lock succession is recorded in the wrong order in the revision history

Tags: bug, migration, revisions-list, post-ban

Scenario: attempting to migrate a question to SO. The asker is question-blocked. I get a popup telling me that the asker is blocked from asking questions and the migration is automatically rejected. So far so good.

Migrating a question locks the question on the source site, and rejecting the migration unlocks it.

[image: screenshot]

The lock and unlock events are in the wrong order in the revision history.

Comment: Have a linky to the revision history?

Comment: @Undo I'm a bit reluctant to give that question-blocked user too much exposure, as this is normally private information. Do you need that information, or is this just for the devs (in which case I can provide a link in a private chatroom if needed)?

Comment: If it is impossible to validate a bug without exposing sensitive information, it is suggested that you use the contact link to send them an email with a complete report.

Comment: @Emrakul You have enough information to validate the public aspect bug from my description and screenshot. You do not have enough information to match it with any internal logs, but a link wouldn't help you there either. I don't understand why you feel you need a link.